# Goal destination using a virtual page in analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am quite new to GA and I've been presented with a big challenge to solve:

- We have a social media campaign that directs traffic to a specific page on our website.
- On that page there is a link to a page on another site.

I need to track how much traffic the social media campaign generates to the page on the other website.

I have so far:

- Created a virtual pageview that is triggered when the link on our website is clicked
- Created a goal in which the destination goal is the virtual page

Is this  the correct approach. Do I need a goal funnel? How do I track the social media campaign with the goal?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, more better setup cross-domain tracking. In result you'll see first source (your social media campaign) whihtout referral traffic.